# Windows 7 and Windows 8 Desktop WPF Touch and Mouse LeftButtonDown Event handling differences

Tags: wpf, windows-7, event-handling, windows-8, touch

I created a Border on a WPF User Control and signed up for the Touch Down and the Mouse Left Button Down Event.

```
    <Border 
            TouchDown="Border_TouchDown_1" 
            MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown_1">

        <Label FontSize="28">Label</Label>
    </Border>
```

In the code behind file I have following event handlers:

```
    private void Border_TouchDown_1(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Result.Append("Border_TouchDown_1" + "\n");
        LogText = Result.ToString();
        RaisePropertyChange();
    }
    private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Result.Append("Border_MouseLeftButtonDown_1" + "\n");
        LogText = Result.ToString();
        RaisePropertyChange();
    }
```

On a Touch Gesture in windows 8 I see both event handlers getting triggered even if the event is handled in the Border_TouchDown_1 method. 
In Windows 7 I see only the Border_TouchDown_1 method gets called which seemed to be correct because the event is handled.

I guess Microsoft concisely decided to fire both events to make all Applications Touch aware which is ok for Mouse only application but my application is Touch aware and I would like to switch this behavior off.

Anybody with some insides out there???

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm trying to get around this right now as well.

Comment: No - we wrote our own low level touch handler.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what will blow your mind?  If you DO NOT set `e.Handled = true`, you won't get the mouse event (at least for PreviewTouchDown / PreviewMouseDown).  It's almost like someone made a typo for windows 8 and it is working backwards.